# Twitter Digits : how to check if the user is already registered

Tags: android, twitter-digits

I am experimenting with [Digits](https://get.fabric.io/digits) API by Twitter for registering users on my Android application. Currently in my launching activity I display a button(`com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsAuthButton`) that asks for users to enter their phone number so that a confirmation code could be sent. Once they enter the confirmation code and are authenticated, I receive a `user_id` in the callback method.

Now, next time if I click on the same button in the launching activity it doesn't display the option to enter the phone number and just returns back the same `user_id` which was already registered.

I want to replicate this same thing in my Java code without that extra click of the `com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsAuthButton` button. I had a look at some samples and they use the following statement to verify the same:

```
if (Digits.getSessionManager().getActiveSession() != null) { ... }
```

Is this sufficient or should I use sharedPreference to store the returned `user_id` with the phone number too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Personally i'm using `sharedpreference` it works well for me..

as for handling "change in phone number later on" you can create a log out Button to turn a `preference` from true to false.

Or

you can check change in phone number:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =     (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

//Required Permission:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I had a look at this code, this is a session recorder to probably track logins after the success callback is triggered. My question is about checking the status of registration , the snippet i have posted as a checker is also from the same sample.

Comment: so you need to check if the user already logged in, if yes he wont see login button?

Comment: Yes, one way is to rely on Digits.sessionmanager.getactivesession() , another way is to use sharedpreference in my App once the success callback is called (similar to what you have suggested). I am confused as to which one to use , and how would it handle change in phone number later on.

Comment: What all do you think I should store in the sharedPreferences ? I am thinking of storing only 'user_id' and 'phonenumber'.

Comment: yes @pankaj store them + true or false would do it!

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but may be helpful for a beginner.To verify that the session is already active, please put this code in your `onCreate` of that activity in which Digits phone  number verification button is initialised:

```
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
            Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits.Builder().build());
    if (Digits.getActiveSession() != null) {
                Intent ss = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(ss);
                finish();
            }
```

And whenever you want to retrive phone number then call  :

`String phone = Digits.getActiveSession().getPhoneNumber();`